# how to read hdfs file with wildcard character used by pyspark

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, parquet

there are some parquet file paths are:

**/a/b/c='str1'/d='str'**

**/a/b/c='str2'/d='str'**

**/a/b/c='str3'/d='str'**

I want to read the parquet files like this:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('/a/b/c='*'/d='str')
```

but it doesn't work by using `"*"` wildcard character.How can I do that? thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape single quotes:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('/a/b/c=\'*\'/d=\'str\'')
```

... or just use double quotes:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("/a/b/c='*'/d='str'")
```

Comment: @ZhangXin hm, it should work. Does the HDFS path contain those quotes? Also, please provide the _exact_ code you have - `'/a/b/c='*'/d='str'` is not a valid Python string