# Conditional loading of partitions from file-system

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, avro, spark-avro

I am aware that there have been questions regarding wildcards in pySparks `.load()`-function like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639956/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-in-a-single-load) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50312789/how-to-read-hdfs-file-with-wildcard-character-used-by-pyspark/50378672).
Anyhow, none of the questions/answers I found dealt with my variation of it.

## Context

In pySpark I want to load files directly from HDFS because I have to use databricks avro-library for Spark 2.3.x. I'm doing so like this:

```py
partition_stamp = "202104"

df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro") \
        .load(f"/path/partition={partition_stamp}*") \
        .select("...")
```

As you can see the partitions are deriving from timestamps in the format `yyyyMMdd`.

## Question

Currently I only get all partitions used for April 2021 (`partition_stamp = "202104"`).
However, I need all partitions starting from April 2021.

Written in pseudo-code, I'd need a solution something alike this:

```py
.load(f"/path/partition >= {partition_stamp}*")
```

Since there actually exist several hundred partitions it is no use to do it in any fashion that requires hard-coding.

So my question is: **Is there a function for conditional file-loading?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learned there exist only the following options to dynamically process paths inside the `.load()`-function:

```
*:  Wildcard for any character or sequence of characters until the end of the line or a new sub-directory ('/') -> (/path/20200*)
[1-3]: Regex-like inclusion of a defined character-range -> (/path/20200[1-3]/...)
{1,2,3}: Set-like inclusion of a defined set of characters -> (/path/20200{1,2,3}/...)
```

Thus, to answer my question: **There is no built-in function for conditional file-loading.**

---

Anyhow, I want to provide you my solution:

```py
import pandas as pd # Utilize pandas date-functions

partition_stamp = ",".join((set(
                        str(_range.year) + "{:02}".format(_range.month) 
                        for _range in pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')
                 )))

df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro") \
        .load(f"/path/partition={{{partition_stamp}}}*") \
        .select("...")
```

This way the restriction for a timestamp of format `yyyyMM` is generated dynamically for a given start- and end-date and the string-based `.load()` is still usable.